# ImportError: cannot import name 'ParameterSource' from 'click.core'

Tags: python, importerror

I'm working on simple flask app, and I received this error

```
    from click.core import ParameterSource
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParameterSource' from 'click.core' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py)
```

I don't know why it's appearing, because everything was fine and then just...

Here are versions I use:

```
black 23.1.0
click 8.1.3
Flask 2.2.3
Python 3.10.6
pip 22.0.2
```

I've been searching for solution and found that many people can't deal with this problem, and the only advice I found, is that I have to update Click and black to the latest version, but I'm already using the latest version.

What should I do? I there any any way to not use Click at all?

UPDATE

Here is how full error looks like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/diametr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import Flask as Flask
  File "/home/diametr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import cli
  File "/home/diametr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 15, in <module>
    from click.core import ParameterSource
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParameterSource' from 'click.core' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py)
```

Comment: `ParameterSource` was added 3 years ago.  Are you deploying this Flask app onto another server?  Are you sure its versions are compatible?

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy it anywhere, I'm just running it locally. What do you mean by version compatibility?

Comment: Your complaint doesn't make sense.  I see the error, but unless the file has been modified, it's right there in the source code.  If you look at the file (the path is in the error), do you find `ParameterSource`?

Comment: Well, what if there is no `dist-packages` inside of `python3.10`? The only folder in `python3.10` is `site-packages`

Comment: There has to be `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`.  Sure you're looking in the right spot?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue yet? I am having the same error (using Python 3.8, click 8.1.3) and can't find a way to fix it yet

Answer (score 9):

Please try the following steps:

```
 pip uninstall black
 pip uninstall click
 pip install black
 pip install click
```

Comment: I've tried, it's not working

Answer (score 2):

hopefully enough I found a solution to that. I replaced the installed version with version 8.1.6
Here are the steps

```
sudo apt purge python3-click
sudo pip install click==8.1.6
```

This solved that issue for me. Hope it helps you too

Answer (score 0):

You can soft reboot your server. Use

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Created another environment and launched my notebook there, I was able to resolve it this way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

```
sudo apt purge python3-click
pip install click
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

I met the problem as the same. But when I changed the current working directory the problem disapper. Perhasp the click call the PWD as the first calling routine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).